# Is it possible to receive a Stringlist from C++ DLL?

Tags: inno-setup, dllimport, pascalscript

I need to get a list of string from my C++ DLL. I know how to use the DLL and already do it several times in the `[code]` section with simple data types e.g. `Boolean` or `Integer`. However now I need to get a list of string to fill a combo box this way, but I've no idea where I could start. I've read that if I want to get a `String` I need to allocate memory on Inno Setup side.

So my questions are:

- How can I receive a stringlist from my C++ DLL function or
  is it possible to fill a combo box on C++ side and return this one instead? - If both is possible what would be easier on Inno Setup side?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate the Inno Setup combo box in your C++ code, if you pass its HWND to the DLL (use `TWinControl.Handle`).

---

If you want to pass a list of strings from DLL back to the Inno Setup, I'd suggest you to add two functions to the DLL:

```pascal
function GetComboBoxItemsCount: Integer;
procedure GetComboBoxItemString(Index: Integer; Str: PChar; MaxLength: Integer);
```

Make `GetComboBoxItemsCount` return number of items. And then call `GetComboBoxItemString` in a loop to retrieve individual strings.

Comment: Well good point with the 2 functions. I would write a function in c++ which gives me number of items and call the 2nd dll function in a loop. On Inno side I just know that there're values but have no idea how many or which one. However I just found that it's possible to work with windows handles on inno setup. Could I use a HWND to combobox i build on c++ side and just show the combobox in the setup?

Comment: *Could I use a HWND to combobox i build on c++ side and just show the combobox in the setup?* That's for a new question. It's way to complicated to be answered in a comment.

Comment: Do you need any more help on my answer? Or is it clear?

Comment: It's clear and accepted. To the new question give me a simple yes/no here in comments I'll try to figure it out myself then before asking a new question ;)

Comment: I assume there's no way to add combo box to Inno Setup window by returning its HWND from DLL. But you definitely can pass the Inno Setup window HWND to the DLL and add a combo box to the window in the DLL.

Comment: I just realized that you obviously can populate the combo box in C++ code, using the WinAPI functions. Previously I was thinking about the `TComboBox` wrapper class only. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Would you be so nice to add 1-2 lines of code how to set up the wincontrol?

Comment: Okay i got it, i can use the combobox.handle itself or i could use myPage.surface.handle ;) thank you again